# gaesession on Google App Engine with Python: KeyError?

Tags: google-app-engine

I used [gaesessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) on Google App Engine with Python to handle user login sessions. The following are some of my codes:

When a user logs in:

```
from gaesessions import get_current_session
...

session = get_current_session()
if session.is_active():
    session.terminate()
session['account'] = account
# Do some stuff to log the user in
```

When the user logs out:

```
session = get_current_session()
account = session['account']
# Do some stuff to log the user out
```

The above codes worked just fine most of the time, except that sometimes (very rarely, maybe once in a month) GAE complained about the statement `account = session['account']` when the user logs out with the error message: `KeyError: 'account'` I wonder if anybody has encountered the same problem?

BTW, I also clean up expired sessions as below. Is it necessary? (I have no idea when a session goes expired) Or could it be the cause of the problem? Thanks.

```
while not delete_expired_sessions():
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `session` dictionary doesn't have the `account` key set to anything. This could be that a request runs your logout method without being logged in. This could happen by someone who is not logged in, yet visits your logout handler.

Eg. A user requests `yourwebsite.com/logout` without being actually logged in yet.

Comment: Brilliant! It's got to be it! Thanks a million, Albert.